# using sed replace a string in solaris

Tags: linux, sed, solaris

I have below file:

```
.   TAU 4236-DA 20
4236-DA - SMS
4236-DA - EMAIL
MID=4236,SC=
{AnyText}
,DABAL1=
{AnyText}
,DAEXP1=
{AnyText}
,MSISDN=
{AnyText}
»
«
.   TAU 3065-DA 20
3065-DA - SMS
3065-DA - EMAIL
MID=7364,DABAL1=
{AnyText}
,DAEXP1=
{AnyText}
,MSISDN=
{AnyText}
,USEDVAL=
{AnyText}
,EXCESS=
{AnyText}
»
```

i want below output:

```
.   TAU 4236    20
4236-DA - SMS
4236-DA - EMAIL
MID=4236,SC=
{AnyText}
,DABAL1=
{AnyText}
,DAEXP1=
{AnyText}
,MSISDN=
{AnyText}
»
«
.   TAU 3065    20
3065-DA - SMS
3065-DA - EMAIL
MID=7364,DABAL1=
{AnyText}
,DAEXP1=
{AnyText}
,MSISDN=
{AnyText}
,USEDVAL=
{AnyText}
,EXCESS=
{AnyText}
»
```

[I want to remove -DA from . TAU line]. Plz help. Please also note that there are multiple strings in file in place of "-DA" which i want to remove. like "-DA", "-LA", "-MA"

Comment: Please add Solaris version to your question.

Comment: Provide feedback on the provided answers and _accept_ the solution that helped you solve the problem.

Comment: guys thanks alot but my actually my problem is still not solved. this "-DA" string is not actually constant in file. in some places it is "-DA" and in some it is like "-MA", "-EU", "-threshold". i tried using "cat sms-pattern-triggers.ptc-jawad | sed -r 's/(TAU\s+[0-9]{4})-[A-z][A-z]/\1   /g' " but it is also not removing all Alhphabets after dash(-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use grouping to match `TAU XXXX` like this :

```
sed -r 's/(TAU\s+[0-9]{4})-DA/\1   /g' data.txt
```

This will replace `-DA` with 3 spaces when `-DA` is preceding by the group `(TAU\s+[0-9]{4})`

or with `awk` :

```
awk '{ print gensub(/(TAU\s+[0-9]{4})-DA/,"\\1   ","g",$0); }' data.txt
```

Comment: Nice suggestions, but as OP mentioned I don't think `Solaris` supports the `-r` flag for `sed`, but rather only `POSIX`-only options.

Comment: the sed command that you have mentioned above is working but i have tried to replace DA in above command with [A-z] to include all alphabets after dash(-) but it is not working. can you suggest?

Comment: try with `[a-Z]+` in place of DA : `/(TAU\s+[0-9]{4})-[a-Z]+/`